# Bootstrap Hide pop over with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How I auto hide the popover from the form? I allways get  error 'Object doesn't support property or method 'popover'' on this lines:

```
$(this).popover('hide');
$(("#" + $(this).attr("id")) + " .popover").popover('hide');
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="label-panel" id="user-info">
                <div class="login-label">@ViewBag.UserString</div>
                <button type="button" class="information-icon" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"> i</button>
</div>
```

And JQuery

```
                  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
                $('#signup-form').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
                        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                            $(this).popover('hide');
                        }
                        $(("#" + $(this).attr("id")) + " .popover").popover('hide');
                });
```

Comment: Can you please check whether $(("#" + $(this).attr("id")) + " .popover") returns anything in console?

Comment: I get a Object: selector"#undefined .popover"

Comment: Yes your selector is wrong. Please check $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).popover('hide'); Before checking, please make sure that $(this).attr("id") is not undefined.

Comment: I try  $("#user-info .popover").popover('hide'); and get the same error: 'Object doesn't support property or method 'popover''

Comment: @F.Santos provide your complete jquery and html

Comment: I found the problem, But I want one clarification...  what is the purpose of this code `$(("#" + $(this).attr("id")) + " .popover").popover('hide');` what are you trying to do.

Comment: I am try to select the element is to hide. for exemple i have: `<div class="login-label" id="user-info" >@ViewBag.UserString</div>
                <button type="button"  class="information-icon" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"> i</button></div>`

Comment: In the sample code I was `$('this).popover('hide');` but inside this function the popover doesnt recognize the element

Answer (score 0):

Please add a script link to bootstrap and that should resolve your issue. Or download bootstrap.min.js and add it locally. And also check you selectors returns something.

You can get the needed files from this [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/). And also please check whether you are loading jQuery more that one time. And also add the reference of extra js files after the jQuery script reference.

If you add the reference of jQuery after the bootstrap reference, you will get this error.

```
"bootstrap.min.js"
"jquery.min.js"
```

You can see that I am getting the same error in my jsFddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/stLu5255/2/) too. So please make sure that you are loading jQuery first then the other js files.

Comment: I have in that order in the line:  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); he pass and show the popover but in the function he doesnt reconize the popover function